# Asp.net Website is only accessible on our company internet connection and not from other network

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure if I am posting this in the correct section?

I have released my asp.net website yesterday on our server, everything went well, I can access the website and even on my phone (connected to company WIFI). When I disconnected from the WIFI on my phone and went back to my standard network, it takes forever to load and eventually just says:

`Internet could not load the web page because [website] took to long to respond. The website may be down or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection`

This was quite strange, I then re-enabled my WIFI on my phone, and viola, I have full access to the website and all features are working. The same issue is happening when I tried to access the site from my home computer.

I am using MVC 3. SSL is enabled on the application.

I had a basic Asp.Net web application which just showed the look and feel to please the clients. That I released the same as this and I could access it anywhere from external or internal networks, so it is really strange. Am I missing a step?

The weirdest part for me is that it works at my company, but I cannot access it from out side. The IIS on the server's binding setting for this application is also set to HTTPS on port 443.

Please let me know if you require more information as I will try my best to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not developed for a mobile phone, it was just a way for me to test that I can access the website.

Comment: Is it behind some firewall that allows access from intranet?

Comment: Since, you said you have released another app in the same way, I assume the only difference is SSL. Most probably the port is blocked or firewall restricts the inbound calls

Comment: Hi @PunitGanshaniMVP, Yes it does, and I had to contact our server house. The specialist had removed https from the firewall and once he added it back again it worked. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Hi @Thangadurai, yes it was in the firewall which did not allow https connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was as  Punit Ganshani MVP asked. The firewall at our server house only allowed http and once https was added to the list the site worked instantly.

Thanks for the suggestion. This was my first asp.net project so i just assumed that I messed something up in the code or the project itself.